# Scrapy Is not Crawling Anything

Tags: python, selenium, scrapy

[image: When I am running it in terminal the output is][image]Scrapy Crawler is Crawling when i run the code in terminal but it is not working when i am running the same in editor. My Code is:

```
from scrapy import Spider
from selenium import webdriver
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request
class BooksSpider(Spider):
    name = 'books'
    allowed_domains = ['books.toscrape.com']


def start_request(self, response):
    self.driver=webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\Night-Watch\Desktop\chromedriver.exe')
    self.driver.get('http://books.toscrape.com')
    sel=Selector(text=self.driver.page_source)


    books=sel.xpath('//h3/a/@href').extract()
    print(books)
```

Comment: How are running the code in editor? Also, can you add the code that starts the crawler?

Comment: https://github.com/clemfromspace/scrapy-selenium

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you sure you want to scrape simple test site using Selenium? It's quite overhead.
2. Can you provide error text and stack trace to get whole picture of the situation.

Comment: I think this should be a comment.

Comment: Yep, comment would be better here.

Comment: @MichaelSavchenko Uploaded the image